# Expressjs can not set cookie in the frontend of reactjs after authorization by bcrypt

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, mongoose, bcrypt

i am using reactjs to create a online shopping web, and use express js to do backend, when i authorize user login, i can not set cookie to the front end

**controller/user/login** from expressjs

```
// user.controller
 bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password, (err, result) => { 
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return res.status(401).json({ message: "password problem" });
                }


                if (result) {
                    const userId = JSON.stringify(user[0]._id);
                    res.cookie('userId', userId, { httpOnly: true, secure: true });
                    return res.status(200)
                        .json({
                            message: userId
                        })
                }
                return res.status(401).json({ message: "Auth failed" });
            })
```

***app.js*** from express

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyPaser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cookiePareser = require('cookie-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const productRouter = require('./api/routes/products');
const orderRouter = require('./api/routes/orders');
const userRouter = require('./api/routes/user');

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://conor_9tails:Mongoatlas123@cluster0-xcpy1.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    {
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    }
);

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log("connected to mongo atlas");
});

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cookiePareser());
// app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
app.use(bodyPaser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyPaser.json());

app.use(cors({ origin: "*" }));

app.use('/products', productRouter);
app.use('/orders', orderRouter);
app.use('/user', userRouter);
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const error = new Error('Not found');
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(error.status || 500);
    res.json({
        error: {
            message: error.message
        }
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

then i make an middleware called auth normally just print out the cookie userId

***check-auth.js*** from middleware/checkauth from expressjs

```
module.exports.requireAuth = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("THIS IS cookies", req.cookies);
    next();
};
```

from the front end, i create a login component from reactjs

```
 handleSubmit(event) {
        let { email, password } = this.state;

        fetch("http://localhost:5000/user/login", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email, password
            }),
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((json) => {
                console.log(json);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

as you can see i console.log response.json() which contain message of userId and it succeeded [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjaVq.jpg)

but there is no cookie was stored in the Application of Chrome

Thank you for your time to help me tackle with this daunting problem

Comment: You said that cookie should be HTTP only, your client code won't be able to read it.

Comment: thank for your help but even i remove it, it not work also

Comment: Then we'll need more information. Is this a cross-origin request, for example? Give a [mre].

Comment: i use module "cors" and already handle it by app.use(cors({ origin: "*" })); in file app.js to handle cross-origin request

Comment: [Edit] the question, it'll take forever to provide all the context in comments (and be largely unreadable).

Comment: yeah, i made edition for the question, please help me that i have no idea what happen, when i made a test route in app.js of express send a cookie to react, the front end side still get that cookie perfectly, but when it comes to this route, it returns null object